# Assign random values from existing vector to a growing vector inside a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, indexing

In the loop below k is assigned random integers in the interval `[1, 1000]`.

On the first 3 loop rounds, k could be: `[5]`, `[2 6]` and `[5 1 5]` for instance.

To a vector `rnd_A`, I want to assign values from a vector `A`, that corresponds to the k indices.

So on the third round, in the example above, I would like to get: `rnd_A(1)= A(5)`, `rnd_A(2)=A(1)` and `rnd_A(3)=A(5)`.

Is it possible to do that with one line of code or maybe two(one for dimensioning?)?

```
for i = 1:1000
   k = randi([1,1000],[i,1]);

   'assign values to rnd_A'

   'do something with rnd_A'
   .
   .

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `k` to index `A` and assign that to `rnd_A`:

```
rnd_A = A(k);
```

Or, if `rnd_A` has more entries and you want to preserve their values, use

```
rnd_A(1:numel(k)) = A(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `A` is your vector:

```
idx = randi(length(A), 1, length(A)); % random sequence of integer as index
rnd_A = A(idx); % index into A
```

This is in two lines, you can make it into one line.

```
rnd_A = A(randi(length(A), 1, length(A)));
```

Comment: @user2042719 Then better make it length-invariant by `length(A)`, which is more meaningful. :)

Comment: @user2042719 Is this what you expect to have? If so, you can upvote and adopt as answer.

Comment: @user2042719 You can adopt it as answer to illustrate this issue is resolved. Convention in this community. :)